# cartesian group of two arrays when grouping in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregate, cartesian-product, group

I am trying to make an aggregation in Mongodb that given the following two documents :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6412b0b1d46ade0d60772017"),
    "patient" : 68494,     
    "records" : [
        {
            "f_8696" : [
                "9670"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
,
{
    
   "_id" : ObjectId("63ea31a439a9436975cf596e"),
   "patient" : 68494,
    "records" : [
        {
            "f_8691" : [
                ISODate("2015-06-15T00:00:00.000+0000")
            ],
            "f_8745" : [
                "9825"
            ],
            "f_8746" : [
                "3556"
            ]
        },
        {
            "f_8691" : [
                ISODate("2015-10-27T00:00:00.000+0000")
            ],
            "f_8745" : [
                "9826"
            ],
            "f_8746" : [
                "3759"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I group them by "patient" and obtain a document that makes a cartesian product of the "records" array:

```
{
    "_id" : {        
        "patient" : 68494
        
    },
    "records" : [      
        [
            {
             "f_8696" : [
                    "9670"
                ],
                "f_8691" : [
                    ISODate("2015-06-15T00:00:00.000+0000")
                ],
                "f_8745" : [
                    "9825"
                ],
                "f_8746" : [
                     "3556"
                ]
            },
            {
              "f_8696" : [
                    "9670"
                ],
                "f_8691" : [
                    ISODate("2015-10-27T00:00:00.000+0000")
                ],
                "f_8745" : [
                    "9826"
                ],
                "f_8746" : [
                    "3759"
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to do this with an aggregate pipeline in MongoDB?

I have tried lots of pipelines stage options, but I think I need a deeper knowledge on MongoDB to be able to do this (if it is even possible)